# Material Design Lite Cards don't align properly

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I'm trying to make a MDL website. I've bumped into some problems... After adding some cards they don't align one next to the other horizontally, but one next to the other vertically leaving a big white space on the right part of the screen which will remain without any content. To give you more info here's the code:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">

            <header class="mdl-layout__header">

                <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">

                    <!-- Title -->

                    <span class="mdl-layout-title">C. Piersigilli &#38 Associati </span>

                    <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->

                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

                </div>

            </header>

            <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">

                <span class="mdl-layout-title"> Navigation </span>

                <nav class="mdl-navigation">

                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> WebMail </a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Contacts </a>

                </nav>

            </div>

            <main class="mdl-layout__content">

                <div class="page-content">

                    <div class="mdl-grid">

                        <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone">

                            <figure class="mdl-card__media">

                                <img src="./images/mdlLogo.png" alt="" />

                            </figure>

                            <div class="mdl-card__title">

                                <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>

                            </div>

                            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>

                            </div>

                            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">

                                <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>

                                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

                                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
                                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

                <div class="mdl-grid">

                    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-phone card-lesson mdl-card mdl-color--indigo mdl-shadow--2dp">

                        <div class="mdl-card__title">

                            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">"Hello, World!"</h2>

                        </div>

                        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

                            The first thing we need to do is define where we want to keep our workspace. Our workspace is simply the folder on our computer where all of our projects are stored. Select                         or...

                        </div>

                        <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">

                            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Learn More</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </main>

        </div>
```

The code itself is really simple and I don't understand why it keeps aligning the wrong way.

As requested here's the CSS as well:

```
.mdl-card__media {

    margin: 0;

}

.mdl-card__media > img {

    max-width: 100%;

}

.mdl-card__actions {

    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;

}

.mdl-card__actions > .mdl-button--icon {+

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;

}

.mdl-layout-title {

    font-family: "Roboto Mono" ;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You'll need to post the CSS as well.

Comment: Indeed...demo it or it didn't happen! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having mdl-card and mdl-cell in the same div, wrap the cards in cells making one cell aligned each other horizontally.

`<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cel--3-col">
 <div class="mdl-card"></div>
 </div>`

Comment: I recently resolved my problems this way, anyway thank you!